# How to get the name of the user that launched `sudo`

Tags: users, sudo, python

My problem: I have a Python program, and the user launch it using `sudo`. Sometimes I have to get the user's home, and I can do this only knowing its name:

```
import pwd

pwd.getpwnam(username)
```

So: how can I get the name of the user that launched the program?

Comment: Inder most configurations, `sudo` leaves the `HOME` environment variable intact (this can be overridden at compile- or run-time). But you may or may not be able to use the environment variable, depending on what you want to happen if the user specifies a different value for `HOME` (what if bob runs `HOME=/home/joe sudo your_script`?). You should probably **set your euid to the calling user** (given by `SUDO_UID`) before making any filesystem access (apart from whatever actually requires root permission in your script).

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Ok, I will set my `euid` to `SUDO_UID`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

When you fire off something with `sudo` a couple of environment variables get set, specifically I think you are looking for `SUDO_UID`. These should be accessible to any program running through the usual channels of accessing environment variables.

You can see the other things set by cheating like this from a shell: `sudo env | grep SUDO`

Comment: +1 WoW! Thank you very much! That was exactly what I was looking for. I think I will use `SUDO_UID` and `SUDO_USER`. Thank you again.

Comment: `SUDO_USER` was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I currently use for covering systemd (="root"), sudo, pkexec and normal execution. Could be made more beautiful for sure:

```py
import os
import getpass
import pwd

def get_user():
    """Try to find the user who called sudo/pkexec."""
    try:
        return os.getlogin()
    except OSError:
        # failed in some ubuntu installations and in systemd services
        pass

    try:
        user = os.environ['USER']
    except KeyError:
        # possibly a systemd service. no sudo was used
        return getpass.getuser()

    if user == 'root':
        try:
            return os.environ['SUDO_USER']
        except KeyError:
            # no sudo was used
            pass

        try:
            pkexec_uid = int(os.environ['PKEXEC_UID'])
            return pwd.getpwuid(pkexec_uid).pw_name
        except KeyError:
            # no pkexec was used
            pass

    return user
```

```bash
➜  ~ python3 /home/mango/getuser.py
mango
➜  ~ sudo python3 /home/mango/getuser.py
mango
➜  ~ pkexec python3 /home/mango/getuser.py
mango
```